# Multiple List comprehension with if-else block

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a below code

```
contraint_attributes_values = []
for item in responses[0].attributes.attributes.values():
    if isinstance(item, list):
        for i in item:
            contraint_attributes_values.append(i['uniqueAttributes']['Name'])
    else:
        contraint_attributes_values.append(item)
```

I am trying to convert this to a list comprehension. I tried certain ways but inside if-else is giving me a problem.

```
[i['uniqueAttributes']['Name'] for item in responses[0].attributes.attributes.values() if isinstance(item, list) for i in item]
```

How far can I build these `for` loops and how exactly does `If-Else` work in there?

Comment: This would get ugly, why are you trying to convert it to a list comprehension, the advantage of which is simply to be more readable?

Comment: So, something like `[x for item in responses[0].attributes.attributes.values() for x in ([i['uniqueAttributes']['Name'] for i in item] if isinstance(item, list) else [item])]` But really, why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: I agree, your original code is clear enough. Not everything gets better when you cram it on one line.

Comment: @Tomalak yeah I agree 100%. To elaborate, list comprehensions are for expressing mapping/filtering operations in a readable, declarative fashion. If it isn't immediately obvious how you could do that, then your code is almost certainly more readable as the loop you already have, and the main advantage of using the list comprehension is gone! So once you have a good understanding of how they work, if you have to *think* about how to create it, you probably *shouldn't do it at all*.

Comment: Of course, as matters of style go, this is fundamentally in the eye of the beholder, but that is your job as a software engineer to make these judgement calls. The way I like to think of things is as follows: if a competent engineer who isn't a Python expert would have trouble understanding something, then don't do it.